# $H^1(G,GL_n(K))$ is trivial.

Tags: galois-cohomology

Suppose $K/F$ is a Galois extension with group $G=\text{Gal}(K/F)$, how to prove that $H^1(G,GL_n(K))$ is trivial with Galois descent?

Thanks.

Comment: See Platonov's [book](https://books.google.at/books?id=NpVdWdFq5YMC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=H%5E1(G,GL_n(K))%3D1+for+G%3DGal(K/F)&source=bl&ots=OYc-iaa2MS&sig=ACfU3U0u88mEhgVAbPxtMNq7ckbnEf4U3Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT4pba7bnmAhWxMewKHbb3C3kQ6AEwAXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=H%5E1(G%2CGL_n(K))%3D1%20for%20G%3DGal(K%2FF)&f=false).

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!